# How to use AngularJS for writing the interface of a node-red custom node?

Tags: angularjs, node-red

I am referring to the .html file associated with the node, not to the UI related nodes. I asked on the official forum and the response was that at the moment Angular is not used. My opinion is that it can be useful for writing nodes faster, without having to use only jQuery.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you referring to https://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/node-html ?  Maybe you can also add the link to the official forum where you have discussed it earlier.  I am also wondering if this is not better discussed in the https://discourse.nodered.org/ forum ?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, at the this time you can not do this. Asking on here isn't going to get you a different answer.

If you want this to change then you need to make a very strong case (on the forum) as to why this needs to be done. The node's config (as described in the nodes HTML file) really shouldn't be that complicated that it needs a complex framework to lay it out.